# Babel in yeoman webapp

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, babeljs

I've been trying for some time to get Babel (6to5) working with yeoman webapp generator but I failed miserably.  I've tried different configurations but none of them worked and I didn't any solution in the Internet.
Does anyone succeeded in getting babel to work with webapp generator? If so, could you share with me your grunt config file?

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

There is a Grunt plug-in for Babel if you haven't gotten to it yet (I know it's been a couple months since you asked).

https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel

Answer (score 0):

There are a [couple official(ish)* solutions](https://github.com/babel/babel-library-boilerplate/issues/58) for babel yeoman generators:

- https://github.com/thejameskyle/generator-es6-library-boilerplate (port of https://github.com/babel/babel-library-boilerplate) for browserify/general usage
- https://github.com/megawac/generator-babel-node (port of https://github.com/jmeas/es6-node-boilerplate) for node/io.js usage specifically.

<sub>* They are yeoman ports of the official boilerplate samples</sub>